# Паттерн Итератор

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования

*Определение* : Паттерн «Итератор»  представляет доступ ко всем элементам составного объекта, не раскрывая его внутреннего представления.

Что подразумевается под "**не раскрывая его внутреннего представления**" ?

Хотелось бы увидеть пример когда открытое представление и закрытое.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Классический пример — `List<T>`. Внутри он содержит по сути массив, в котором несколько последних элементов не используются. Но снаружи массива не видно. Вы можете обойти его через `foreach` (который использует внутри итератор), получить все элементы списка, но внутренний массив вы не увидите.

С другой стороны, `List<T>` мог бы быть имплементирован по-другому, он мог бы выставить свой несущий массив наружу, и итерировать нужно было бы по массиву. Тогда он бы раскрыл внутреннее представление.